# Editing a pandas script to ignore but not remove data then match & updating + comparing to prevent wasteful saves + slicing data to match with?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas, assert

I've got some issue with one of my scripts... I'll put the problems in bullets.

- **Issue/Question 1 - Comparing the original testing.csv to the modified one before saving, if different it should save, if the same it should not save.**

  - In my code below, the data comes out the same but for some reason it thinks it's different and I can't find out why...
- **Issue/Question 2 - Ignoring certain data during a match**

  - I'm wanting to match using `MATCH2` but ignore the parenthesis data for example in the last classes data `MATCH2` has `Mdata (D)` it needs to match by `MData`
- **Issue/Question 3 - Slicing data to match with**

  - I'm wanting to find a way so if I wanted to use `MATCH1` I could set `MATCH1` so that it only uses `MATCH1[-1:]` which would ultimately give me numbers in this example.

#### `Testing.py`

```
import re
import pandas
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

# each block in the text file will be one element of this list
matchers = [[]]
i = 0 
with open('testing.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        # Blocks are seperated by blank lines
        if len(line) == 0:
            i += 1
            matchers.append([])
            # assume there are always two blank lines between items 
            # and just skip to the lext line
            infile.next()
            continue
        matchers[i].append(line)


# This regular expression matches the variable number of students in each block
studentlike = re.compile('(\d+) (.+) (\d+/\d+)')
# These are the names of the fields we expect at the end of each block
datanames = ['Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
# We will build a table containing a list of elements for each student
table = []
for matcher in matchers:
    # We use an iterator over the block lines to make indexing simpler
    it = iter(matcher)
    # The first two elements are match values
    m1, m2 = it.next(), it.next()
    # then there are a number of students
    students = []
    for possiblestudent in it:
        m = studentlike.match(possiblestudent)
        if m:
            students.append(list(m.groups()))
        else:
            break
    # After the students come the data elements, which we read into a dictionary
    # We also add in the last possible student line as that didn't match the student re
    dataitems = dict(item.split() for item in [possiblestudent] + list(it))
    # Finally we construct the table
    for student in students:
        # We use the dictionary .get() method to return blanks for the missing fields
        table.append([m1, m2] + student + [dataitems.get(d, '') for d in datanames])

textcols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'TITLE01', 'MATCH3','TITLE02', 'Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('testing.csv')
csvdata_old = csvdata.copy()
textdata = pandas.DataFrame(table, columns=textcols)

# Add any new columns
newCols = textdata.columns - csvdata.columns
for c in newCols:
    csvdata[c] = None

mergecols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'MATCH3']
csvdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
csvdata_old.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
textdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True,drop=False)

csvdata.update(textdata)

try:
    assert_frame_equal(csvdata, csvdata_old)
    print "True (Same)"
except:
    csvdata.to_csv('testing.csv', index=False)
    print "False (Different)"
```

#### `testing.txt`

```
MData
DMATCH1
3 Tommy 144512/23332
1 Jim 90000/222311
1 Elz M 90000/222311
1 Ben 90000/222311
Data $50.90
misc2 $10.40
bla3 $20.20


MData
DMATCH2
4 James Smith 2333/114441
4 Mike 90000/222311
4 Jessica Long 2333/114441
Data $50.90
bla3 $5.44


Mdata
DMATCH3
5 Joe Reane 0/0
5 Peter Jones 90000/222311
Data $10.91
misc2 $420.00
bla3 $210.00
```

#### `testing.csv`

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE,TITLE
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data
```

#### Desired `testing.csv` after script has been ran...

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,TITLE.1,TITLE.2,TITLE.3,TITLE.4,TITLE.5,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE.6,TITLE.7,Data,TITLE01,TITLE02,bla3,misc2
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Tommy,55,data,data,$50.90,3,144512/23332,$20.20,$10.40
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Ben,54,data,data,$50.90,1,90000/222311,$20.20,$10.40
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jim,52,data,data,$50.90,1,90000/222311,$20.20,$10.40
DMATCH1,MData (N/A),data,data,data,data,data,data,Elz M,22,data,data,$50.90,1,90000/222311,$20.20,$10.40
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,James Smith,15,data,data,$50.90,4,2333/114441,$5.44,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Jessica Long,224,data,data,$50.90,4,2333/114441,$5.44,
DMATCH2,MData (B/B),data,data,data,data,data,data,Mike,62,data,data,$50.90,4,90000/222311,$5.44,
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Joe Reane,66,data,data,$10.91,5,0/0,$210.00,$420.00
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Peter Jones,256,data,data,$10.91,5,90000/222311,$210.00,$420.00
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,data,data,data,data,data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,data,,,,,
```

I'd greatly appreciate the help if anyone can :)

## Edit for bheklilr

#### `testing.txt`

```
Mdata
DMATCH3
5 Joe Reane 0/0
5 Peter Jones 90000/222311
Data $10.91
misc2 $420.00
bla3 $210.00
```

#### `testing.csv`

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Joe Reane,66,data
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Peter Jones,256,data
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Lesley Lope,5226,data
```

#### Desired `testing.csv` after script has been ran...

```
MATCH1,MATCH2,TITLE,MATCH3,DATA,TITLE.1,Data,TITLE01,TITLE02,bla3,misc2
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Joe Reane,66,data,$10.91,5,0/0,$210.00,$420.00
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Peter Jones,256,data,$10.91,5,90000/222311,$210.00,$420.00
DMATCH3,Mdata (D),data,Lesley Lope,5226,data,,,,,
```

Comment: This is a rather large example.  Can you reduce it down to a minimally complete working example?

Comment: @bheklilr See edited section under `Edit for bheklilr` for a smaller textfile, testing.csv and desired output. Normally people reply with "not enough detail" asking for more data in the example so your request is quite baffling.

Comment: your column headers changed order from the larger example to the smaller testing.csv example. Which are you after?

Comment: The ones that requires changes have kept the same header names, my smaller version is just a simplified version...

Answer (score 0):

Going through your example, here's some answers:

## **Question 1**

Comparing the original testing.csv to the modified one before saving, if different it should save, if the same it should not save.

**Answer 1** - They are in fact different. For an example, lets output what each csv looks like near the end of your script:

```
# This is near the end of your script...

mergecols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'MATCH3']
csvdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
csvdata_old.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
textdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True,drop=False)

csvdata.update(textdata)

# Add these 3 lines to dump your files to csv's of the same name.
csvdata.to_csv('csvdata.csv')
csvdata_old.to_csv('csvdata_old.csv')
textdata.to_csv('textdata.csv')

try:
    assert_frame_equal(csvdata, csvdata_old)
    print "True (Same)"
except:
    print "False (Different)"
```

Inspecting the resulting csv files in a text editor, or excel, you will see that `csvdata` and `csvdata_old` are in fact different. And why wouldn't they be. You've added columns to it with this section of python code:

```
>>> textdata.columns - csvdata.columns
Index([Data, TITLE01, TITLE02, bla3, misc2], dtype=object)
```

So, your assert is correct. They're different.

---

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "matching" in Question 2 or 3. What are you trying to match? Do you actually mean group results by a similar column? How would this look? More information would be great!

Comment: It's not on the first loop of running the script, it's on the second loop where the data should be identical, for example in my large example aftersetting TITLE01 to an object `csvdata = pandas.read_csv('testing.csv', dtype={'TITLE01' : 'object'})
` to stop the floating of an int, it says that the output is different yet looking at the data and comparing in notepad++ it returns identical data, even the new lines are the same CRLF see: http://i.imgur.com/TBrGI6X.png

Comment: In my smaller example for bheklilr if you look at the testing.txt the first line (one of the 3 things it matches against testing.csv) it's got `Mdata` where as in my csv it's got `Mdata (D)`, I want to strip the `(D)` parentheses data from the csv MATCH2 column and then match, it doesn't even need to be a regex to know what to strip as there are only 2-3 variations of parentheses data that I need to temporarily strip.